# Can I define a custom pattern for C# Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

So I want to use a pattern that is basically `\s` (whitespaces) except that I don't want to match no-break space (`\160`). It will be a very long string to define all whitespace characters excluding that one. Is there way to define a custom pattern and provide a delegate for it? It'd just be `c => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && c != '\160'`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some sample text?

Comment: Aren't there just six characters in the `\s` group (plus nbsp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET regex, you can use [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html).

> It makes it easy to match any single character present in one list (the character class), but not present in another list (the subtracted class). The syntax for this is `[class-[subtract]]`. If the character after a hyphen is an opening bracket, these flavors interpret the hyphen as the subtraction operator rather than the range operator. You can use the full character class syntax within the subtracted character class.

To exclude just a hard space (`\u00A0`) from the `\s` class, use

```
[\s-[\u00A0]]
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cu00A0%5D%5D&i=I%20know%20that%20here%20is%20a%20hard%C2%A0space.)

As an alternative (since character class subtraction is a .NET-specific feature), you can always rely on a negative look-ahead to restrict a generic class (although the performance is worse here):

```
(?!\u00A0)\s
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F!%5Cu00A0)%5Cs&i=I%20know%20that%20here%20is%20a%20hard%C2%A0space.)

Comment: Thanks! My code is in C#, so .NET specific feature is fine. I wasn't aware of that feature. It comes handy for my purpose.